# Null named Kernel Driver service

Tags: drivers, kernel

I installed Valorant and I learned Vanguard is a 7/24 working Kernel Driver. So I suspected and uninstalled Vanguard and Valorant.

After that, I wanted to check Kernel Drivers on my computer. I ran `sc query type=kernel` on cmd and there is a service named null;

```
SERVICE_NAME: Null
DISPLAY_NAME: Null
    TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I formatted my pc about 3 days ago. Is it normal or should I format my pc again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a normal built-in Windows driver. It provides the `NUL:` or `\Device\Null` [virtual device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), which is the equivalent of /dev/null on Linux and other systems.